# Add sprite in function in Phaser 3

Tags: sprite, phaser-framework, 2d-games

I am adding a sprite to my game like this:

```
enemy = this.physics.add.sprite(280, 32, 'enemy');
```

Now I'd like to add it from inside a function like this:

```
spawn(this.enemy);

function spawn(enemy) {
    enemy = this.physics.add.sprite(280, 32, 'enemy');
}
```

It doesn't work, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: this.physics is undefined
```

What do I have to write instead of `this.physics`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should, instead, use an **[arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)** like so:

First, within the **function `preload()`**, add the sprite:

```
this.load.spritesheet('enemy', 'assets/enemy.png', { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 });
```

*Second, within the **function `create()`,** add the following code:*

```
spawn = (enemyName) => {
    enemyPlayer = this.physics.add.sprite(400, 450, enemyName);
}

spawn('enemy');
```

As you can see, we're passing the **sprite's name** as a **function's parameter**. You can, now, reuse this function to **"spawn"** other **sprites**. For example, **`spawn('stars')`**.

Comment: doesnt explain why "this.physics" is undefined

Comment: Because `this` no longer refers to the same thing when it's within a function; the scope changes, so now the function's `this` doesn't have a `physics` definition.